# $project_path substitutions in a SublimeText2 build-system for Python

Tags: python, sublimetext2, virtualenv

I'm trying to set up a Python build-system for my virtualenv based Python projects.

Generally all my Python virtualenv projects are set up the same way: A single project folder containing /src (where my code lives), and /bin where the virtualenv python interpreter lives along with the activate script.

I want to add $project_path/src to the PYTHONPATH environment variavble. In order to debug this I set up a project like this:

```
{
"build_systems":
[
    {

        "name": "pythonX",
        "env":
        {
            "PYTHONPATH":"${project_path}/xxxxxyy"
        },
        "working_dir": "${project_path:${folder}}/src",
        "cmd":
        [
            "${project_path}/bin/python2.7",
            "-u",
            "$file"
        ]
    }
],
"folders":
[
    {
        "path": "/home/sal/workspace/pythonmoo"
    }
]
}
```

I made a Python script to test this - I just printed out sys.path (which ought to pick up Pythonpath), however I see the following:

```
 '/home/sal/workspace/pythonmoo/src/${project_path}/xxxxxyy',
```

It's clear that the variable did not expand.

What am I doing wrong here? Is there perhaps a better way to achieve my goals?

UPDATE 0:

As suggested I re-implemented this as a .sublime-build file. The results were exactly the same:- variable expansion worked fine in cmd but not in env.

```
{ 
"env":
{
    "PYTHONPATH":"$project_path/src"
},
"working_dir": "${project_path:${folder}}/src",
"cmd":
[
    "${project_path}/bin/python2.7",
    "-u",
    "$file"
]
}
```

Comment: [I'm not sure that you need the curly braces](https://sublime-text-unofficial-documentation.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/build_systems.html?highlight=environment%20variables#build-system-variables) for an environment variable that doesn't require a [place holder](https://sublime-text-unofficial-documentation.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/build_systems.html?highlight=environment%20variables#place-holders-for-variables). Did you try removing them?

Comment: Without the curly-braces you get pretty much the same output: Just the unexpanded variable name, but this time with no curly-braces. Is it possible that the variable substitution does not work in env?

Comment: How bizarre. I shouldn't think `env` would be a problem; perhaps it's instead the fact that you're adding the build system to a `sublime-project` file rather than a `sublime-build` file. Did you try making a custom one of those instead, or is there a reason you need to keep the build file within a `sublime-project` file?

Comment: No difference - could somebody verify that variables can be used in an  env?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you are looking for, but I do something similar and I set `"evn":{"PYTHONPATH":"."}` and it pulls my `src` directory for me.

```
{
    "build_systems": [
        {
            "name": "python-test",
            "cmd": ["${project_path}/Scripts/python", "-u", "$file"],
            "working_dir": "${project_path:${folder}}/src",
            "selector": "source.python",
            "env": {
                "PYTHONPATH": "."
            }
        }
    ],
    "folders": [
        {
            "path": "/C/projects/python/test"
        }
    ]
}
```

Which is created when I run a script that sets up a virtualenv.

The structure for the project `test` is:

```
test/
|-- Include/
|-- Lib/
|-- Scripts/
|-- src/
|   |-- ospaths.py
|   |-- package/
|   |   |-- test.py
```

`ospaths.py`

```
import sys

def get():
    return sys.path
```

`package/test.py`

```
import ospaths

for path in ospaths.get():
    print path
```

Which gives me the following output:

```
C:\projects\python\test\src\package
C:\projects\python\test\lib\site-packages\setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg
C:\projects\python\test\lib\site-packages\pip-1.3.1-py2.7.egg
C:\projects\python\test\src
C:\Windows\system32\python27.zip
C:\projects\python\test\DLLs
C:\projects\python\test\lib
C:\projects\python\test\lib\plat-win
C:\projects\python\test\lib\lib-tk
C:\projects\python\test\Scripts
C:\Python27\Lib
C:\Python27\DLLs
C:\Python27\Lib\lib-tk
C:\projects\python\test
C:\projects\python\test\lib\site-packages
[Finished in 0.6s]
```